# How do i send HTML input fields to my MySQLi database using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send the data put into the input fields to my database and I cant seem to make it work out properly..

The ultimate goal is to put in the input fields into the database and show the inserted data in another window.

Here's my code

```html
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

// create a variable
$naam=$_POST['namen'];
$plaats=$_POST['plaatsen'];
$land=$_POST['landen'];
 
//Execute the query
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO phptoets(Namen,Plaatsen,Landen)
    VALUES('$naam','$plaats','$land')");

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
 <title>PHP Toets</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="import_intel">
 
</div>
<form method="POST">
<div class="invulform">

 <h2>Vul hier de gegevens in die naar de database moeten</h2>

 <input type="text" name="naam" class="input_name" placeholder="Naam"><br>
 <input type="text" name="plaats" class="input_plaats" placeholder="Plaats"><br>
 <input type="text" name="land" class="input_land" placeholder="Land"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit_button" value="Verstuur">
 
</div>
</form>

<div class="overzichtform">
 <h3>Data</h3>
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Warning!** You are **wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: check your connection `new mysqli($servername, $username, $password)`  you don't put your `database`

Comment: it's a local project i have to make for school, so don't worry :)

Comment: You need a <form> tag... search how to create it and send info to the same page.

Comment: _"i cant seem to make it work "_ is not a good description. You need to explain what happens. You should also add some error handling: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: _"it's a local project i have to make for school, so don't worry"_ - It doesn't matter. SQL Injections isn't only for protection against evil people. For example: if any of the parameters contains a single quote or ends with a back slash, your query will break. You should _always_ write good and secure code. Eventually you will reuse some old code in a real project and miss to fix the security issues.

Comment: add database name in connection and use `$conn` instead of `$connect` in `mysqli_query` function with `,` separated query...

Comment: also I can't see any field named as `provincie` that you are using in php

Comment: @YashParekh i tried the method you mentioned and it worked, only now i get some undefined errors on my page,

Comment: @MultiDutch show your error and check my last comment

Comment: 'Notice: Undefined index: namen in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptoets\index.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: plaatsen in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptoets\index.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: landen in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptoets\index.php on line 19'

Comment: You haven't taken the form so how the form posts data to server?? Just take the html fields inside form.

Comment: How are you even posting your inputs? You don't even have a form.

Comment: <form method="post">Then your input code</form>

Comment: i have updated the code in the question..

Comment: What error do you get right now?

Comment: @JelmerBouman `Notice: Undefined index: namen in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptoets\index.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: plaatsen in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptoets\index.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: landen in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptoets\index.php on line 19`

Comment: Take a look at my solution in the answers, that worked for me. Let me know if you don't understand somthing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It will help you. I've done few changes in your code.
  - Add form to post the data on server
  - Add database name in connection
  - Add provincie field in form (because you are trying to get that in php)
  - Use the same variable in query as declared at the time of connection

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "DATABASE";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // create a variable
    $namen=$_POST['naam'];
    $plaatsen=$_POST['plaats'];
    $landen=$_POST['land'];
    $provincie=$_POST['provincie'];

    //Execute the query
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO employees1(naam,plaats,land,provincie) VALUES('$namen','$plaatsen','$landen','$provincie')");
  }

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <title>PHP Toets</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="import_intel">
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="">
      <div class="invulform">
        <h2>Vul hier de gegevens in die naar de database moeten</h2>
        <input type="text" name="naam" class="input_name" placeholder="Naam"><br>
        <input type="text" name="plaats" class="input_plaats" placeholder="Plaats"><br>
        <input type="text" name="land" class="input_land" placeholder="Land"><br>
        <input type="text" name="provience" class="input_provience" placeholder="Provience"><br>
        <input type="button" name="submit" class="submit_button" value="Verstuur">
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="overzichtform">
      <h3>Data</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

You forgot to set database name and the names of your input fields where not equal to your $_POST names.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

// create a variable
$naam=$_POST['naam'];
$plaats=$_POST['plaats'];
$land=$_POST['land'];

//Execute the query
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO phptoets(namen,plaatsen,landen)
                VALUES('$naam','$plaats','$land')");

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <title>PHP Toets</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="import_intel">

</div>
<form method="post">
<div class="invulform">

    <h2>Vul hier de gegevens in die naar de database moeten</h2>

    <input type="text" name="naam" class="input_name" placeholder="Naam"><br>
    <input type="text" name="plaats" class="input_plaats" placeholder="Plaats"><br>
    <input type="text" name="land" class="input_land" placeholder="Land"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit_button" value="Verstuur">

</div>
</form>

<div class="overzichtform">
    <h3>Data</h3>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
// TESTS

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "test"; 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully  <br>";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // create a variable
    $a = (string)filter_input(INPUT_POST,'naam');
    $b = (string)filter_input(INPUT_POST,'plaats');
    $c = (string)filter_input(INPUT_POST,'land');
    $d = (string)filter_input(INPUT_POST,'provincie');

    echo("executing query <br>");
    //Execute the query
    if($a != null && $b != null && $c != null && $c != null)
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO employees1 (naam,plaats,land,provincie) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        echo("sql ".$sql. "<br>");
        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$a,$b,$c,$d);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }

    $sql = "SELECT naam, plaats, land, provincie FROM employees1";      
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) 
    {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($naam,$plaats,$land,$provincie);  
        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            printf("naam : %s, plaats: %s, land: %s, provincie: %s <br>",$naam,$plaats,$land,$provincie);
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <title>PHP Toets</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="import_intel">

</div>

<div class="invulform">

    <h2>Vul hier de gegevens in die naar de database moeten</h2>
    <form class="my_form" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="naam" class="input_name" placeholder="Naam"><br>
        <input type="text" name="plaats" class="input_plaats" placeholder="Plaats"><br>
        <input type="text" name="land" class="input_land" placeholder="Land"><br>
        <input type="text" name="provincie" class="input_land" placeholder="Provincie"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit_button" value="Verstuur">
    </form>
</div>

<div class="overzichtform">
    <h3>Data</h3>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I will just name few things that I changed in your code, not mentioning syntax errors

1. you dont specify db_name in your sql connection
2. you dont use prepared statements nor any kind of input filtering
   (note : my input filtering is very basic, read more about how to
   filter inputs)
3. to address html form you need to create one and have submit input
   type inside